# How to get this value with only one xpath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to have an XPATH which is able to select the date and time (like june 19 2020 at 08:59 pm) in all cases:

```
<span class="post_date"><span title="June 21, 2020 at 08:18 AM" currentmouseover="12">1 hour ago</span> <span class="post_edit" id="edited_by_2462600"> </span></span>

<span class="post_date" currentmouseover="62">June 19, 2020 at 08:56 PM <span class="post_edit" id="edited_by_2454907"> </span></span>

<span class="post_date" currentmouseover="157"><span title="June 20, 2020" currentmouseover="168">Yesterday</span> at 10:41 AM <span class="post_edit" id="edited_by_2457722"> </span></span>
```

I can get the second one easily with `//*[@class="post_date"]/text()`, but is there any way to get the 2 others and have 1 xpath for all cases? Or am I better off writting a function for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working XPath expression to select all dates with one expression :

```
(//@title|//text())[contains(.,", ") or contains(.," at ")]
```

Output : 4 nodes

[image: Nodes]

EDIT : If you need something stronger (assuming all messages were posted after year 2000).

```
//span[@class='post_date']/span[contains(@title,', 20')]/@title|//span/text()[contains(.,' at ') and contains (.,':')][ancestor::*[1][self::span][@class='post_date']]
```

Or :

```
(//span[@class='post_date']/span[@title]/@title|//span/text()[ancestor::*[1][self::span][@class='post_date']])[contains(.,', 20') or contains(.,' at ')]
```

Output : 4 nodes

Comment: Thanks, valid xpath but unfortunately it will grab a lot of unwanted stuff other phrases contain ", " or " at "
`post_date=r.xpath('(.//@title|.//text())[contains(.,", 2") or contains(.," at ")]').get()`
With this it's close, except it misses the hour for the 3rd case
Is there a way to grave title and text only if text contains " at "?

Comment: OK. Post is edited with 2 more robust XPath expression.